# Why does halving the resolution of camera make a real world object 1.5 times smaller

Tags: math, camera

I feel dumb for not understanding this but here goes.  I have a camera in Android and I take a picture of a square object in the real world. When the camera resolution is set to 1280x720 the size of the object is 150px in the camera.  If I scale that picture by dividing by 2 I'll get 75px.

However if I change the resolution of the camera to be half the resolution, or 640x360, then the size of the object will be 100px.  This is a ration of 1.5 (or 1/1.5 = 0.6666).

I can't quite wrap my head around this, I know it has to have something to do with the object staying the same size while the resolution halves but I still don't get it.

Comment: Does the object really stay the same size? I suspect that the image shows a different portion of the scene. Might have something to do with what pixels of the sensor are used with the different resolutions.

Comment: Can you show the two pictures you are describing? In the end, you might end up getting the question closed for not being programming related. But I for one am curious...

Comment: Yes the object is fixed in size it's a  square colored piece of paper.

Comment: If the focal point (znear) of your camera stays the same then also the FOV angles change with resolution ... they shrink a bit too hence smaller output then expected. The same effect might cause aspect ratio change ...